# how to use global variable in nav ...li href

Tags: javascript, css, variables, href, nav

I want to create a global variable to assign to menu navigation for URLs to different sites.

Following is a snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      li {
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <script>
    var my_name, my_URL2, my_URL1;
    my_name = prompt("What's the my_name");
    my_URL1= "http:__mysite.com/profile.ashx?t="+my_name
    my_URL2= "http:__yoursite.com/profile.ashx?t="+my_name

  </script>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http:__google.com">News</a></li> ////// this works
      <li><a href=my_URL1>Phon</a></li>           ////// variable use fail.
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I really think and hope there is a way to assign a variable to different URLs and user can simply click and head to the URL with that global variable.

If there is another site for getting help, please point me that way.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use JavaScript content in HTML directly. What you may do is:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  urlCont = prompt("Enter URL");
};
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="location.href='https://' + window.urlCont">Phon</a>
```

In the above code to test it out, if you try putting a unsandboxed unrestricted domain like mine `praveen.science`, you will be able to navigate to it.

1. Run the snippet.
2. Enter `praveen.science` or any other unrestricted domain.
3. Press ok in the prompt.
4. Click on the Phon link.
5. The link navigates to the location you put.

But again, this is a worst method of setting anything. Always try using unobtrusive mode.

Comment: I am new to javascript.  what part of a html will the window.onload be placed?  and where does the <a href...click...></a> be placed?

Comment: btw, the solution is trying to get one global variable from prompt and append to the  other variables which will be for the URLs in the nav menu.

Comment: @YA9thGrader You can append it to anything. `<a>` can be placed anywhere in the body. `<script>` can be placed anywhere in the head or body. `:)`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the correct syntax for window.onload for my snippet.  and i am not looking for a prompt to have uesr type the URL.